# Macro with some sort of condition

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming

I'm trying to create an macro so safe me from some typing and make it nicer/easier to define an property, this is what I have in mind:

```
#define DefineProperty(Access, Type, Name) \
property<Access, Type> ##Name; \
void Set##Name(Type); \
Type Get##Name(void); \
```

Where Access is an enum with three possible values: ReadOnly, WriteOnly and ReadWrite. The method in the macro should only be defined if the access value is appropriate for the method.

Is this in any way possible for example using meta-programming?

Comment: There is no such thing as macro metaprogramming.  You probably want partial template specialization here.  Also, using one construct and sometimes defining methods and sometimes not is rather tricky.  What are you really trying to accomplish?  If you have enough use for getters and setters to want to streamline writing them, you're almost certainly writing bad O-O.

Comment: @David - you probably couldn't be more wrong about that.  See boost.preprocessor

Comment: @Noah:  Thank you.  There is such a thing.  I was happier not knowing.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  It's a very powerful and important library.

Comment: @David: I'm trying to acccomplish just what i showed you. Making it easier to define properties. And yes i have an need for them and no it's not bad o-o. I'm using c# a lot and realy like the way properties are working. So i want too do the same in c++.

Comment: "No such thing"? Metaprogramming is literally the entire purpose of macros. They don't do anything else! Look at [Order](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Order) to see how much more powerful they are than templates for metaprogramming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish this fairly easily:

```
#define DefineGetReadOnly(Name, Type)  Type Get##Name();
#define DefineGetReadWrite(Name, Type) Type Get##Name();
#define DefineGetWriteOnly(Name, Type)

#define DefineProperty(Access, Type, Name) \
    DefineGet##Access(Name, Type)
```

The macro replacement takes place as follows:

```
DefineProperty(ReadOnly, int, Foo)
DefineGetReadOnly(Foo, int)
int GetFoo();

DefineProperty(WriteOnly, int, Bar)
DefineGetWriteOnly(Bar, int)
/* no tokens */
```

Comment: @Stacked:  Yeah, it's all about using the right tool for the job.  Macros are often the best tool built into the language when you need automatic code generation.

Comment: That is indeed fairly easy and clean (instead of metaprogramming). Didn't know you could have macros inside macros and even name them like the way you did. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, McNellis's answer is fairly straightforward and simple.  But, if you're interested, it is quite possible to build exactly what you're after using template metaprogramming as well.  I've been refining a library to do just that for the last year.

I can't share it all, it's proprietary and not owned by me.  But I can point you in the direction I found to be the easiest to use.  Check out the techniques described in 9.5 of C++ Template Metaprogramming by Abrahams and Gurtovoy.  Compare it to things like boost::tuple and boost::fusion objects.  Note that you can declare "names" by defining new types.  Thus you can create something you might use like so:

```
struct object_with_properties : construct_property_object< mpl::vector< mpl::pair< property<access,type>, name> ... > >::type
{};

object_with_properties owp;
get<name>(owp);
set<name>(owp, value);

// or maybe
get<name>(owp) = value;
```

My system actually allows you to define such objects that's properties are implemented by functions.  It's much more complex though and I've not found a way to simplify it to the above degree.  For that I started with an article called "Reflection support by means of template metaprogramming" that's out on the net somewhere...might have pulled it from ACM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm actually interested in it, but i opt for the cleaner/simpler approach for now pointed out by James. I need to get that book some time and learn more about metaprogramming.